# How to make two labels with autolayout have the same text size?

Tags: ios, swift, label

I have two labels (labelOne and labelTwo) which I want to have the same text size. Using autolayout labelTwo tends to be bigger than labelOne and as such has a larger font size. I have tried using the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
labelOne.font = UIFont(name: labelTwo.font!.fontName, size: labelTwo.font!.pointSize)
```

as suggested in this question: [Autoshrink labels, but maintain same font size for every other UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744359/autoshrink-labels-but-maintain-same-font-size-for-every-other-uitableviewcell)
but this does not work for me.

Comment: Not much to go on here. When are you calling this? Are the fonts also being set somewhere else, i.e., storyboards? Try setting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false for both labels?

Comment: I have tried this but it cuts off some of the font on the IPhone SE. is it possible for xcode to auto layout the smaller label and scale the text to fill, and then take that size and apply it to the larger label? I can update my answer if it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you've found a solution but I had a similar issue.

I solved it by making the labels the same width and aspect ratio, autoshrink on with minimum font scale.  Here's the charm though: Lines=0.

Somebody mentioned having the same number of characters, but that doesn't work on all fonts.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you set the label to a fixed font size. Your font size is probably changing when the view controller calls layout subviews.

[image: UI label attribute inspector]

Comment: I have tried this but it cuts off some of the font on the IPhone SE. is it possible for xcode to auto layout the smaller label and scale the text to fill, and then take that size and apply it to the larger label?

Comment: It is possible to use size classes (different static font sizes per device) all you have to do is pick a layout size on the bottom.

Comment: Cant attest to reading the font size of a label and setting it to another label. I'd imagine you will need to do it in the didLayoutSubviews method

Answer (score -1):

Labels have intrinsic content size. You need to make them have the width and height constraints and make an equality relation between them.
[image]

Comment: This solution was my first attempt at fixing the issue but they still have differing font sizes for some reason...