# Set the same font size for two labels within a horizontal stack view with autolayout and authoshrink

Tags: ios, fonts, uikit, label, autolayout

I need to create a view in which I want to have two labels side by side with equal spacing. The problem is that those labels will have different texts depending on the backend response. I want to adjust the font size of the two labels equally because now when one of the two labels have a very large text, autolayout only adjusts that label. Also this approach will help me with smaller screen like the iPhone SE, because same thing happens. How can I achieve that?

[image: Problem]

I did try setting equal width, height, and aspect ratio constraints, but there's no way I can achieve what I want. Also it's very important that the two labels stay aligned on the top left (I've achieved that by setting horizontal stack alignment to top).

One of the things that I have tried:

[image: One of the things that I have tried]

I have also tried the solutions [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597749/how-to-make-two-labels-with-autolayout-have-the-same-text-size) but it's not working for me.

**More info and real example:**
[real example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA1yp.png)
Ok so the expected layout is the following:

1- I have a vertical stack view with one label and the horizontal stack view

2- The horizontal stack view have the following insets:
[horizontal stack view insets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnVTm.png)

3- The horizontal stack view have the distributions= equal spacing

4- The two labels have autoshrink enabled and minimum font size of 9pts

The things is that if I want to ad a very long item name in one of the two labels I need the other one to have the same fon size and both labels need to stay touching the horizontal stack view margins and keep the items in the same line. For example:
In one hand the "Very very very long item name" should stay in the same line and adjust both labels fonts size in order to do that, and in the other hand the "LongItemNameWithoutSpaces" should do the same.
[Example with long names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMaFq.png)

Comment: Do you need the labels to be equal widths?

Comment: Not really I just need that the two labels keep the same font size and be centered with equal spacing in the horizontal stack view

Comment: If you have only TWO labels, it's not clear what you mean by "equal spacing"? Can you do a couple screen-caps showing exactly how you want it to look, using several different "real-world" text strings?

Comment: @DonMag I've added more info. If you could help me I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: OK - still not quite clear... do you want each **pair** of labels to match font size? Or, do you want **all** the labels to match? So, Left or Right version of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysbya.png ... or something else?

Comment: @DonMag I’m really sorry for my bad explanations… I want all the labels to match, so the right version is the one that I need and your example seems perfect. How did you do that with autolayout?

Comment: We cannot do that with auto-layout only... gotta use some code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for "matching" label auto-shrink font sizes.

To accomplish that, you'll need to:

- loop through the strings in the list
- find the smallest font size that will fit the longest text
- loop through the labels again setting that font to all the labels

We can use code along these lines...

Assuming we have these properties:

```
let defaultFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
let maxFontSize: CGFloat = 16.0
let minFontSize: CGFloat = 9.0
let rowSpacing: CGFloat = 4.0
let columnSpacing: CGFloat = 20.0

// array of strings
let items: [String] = [
    "Carrots", "Tomatos",
    "Bananas", "Cola",
    "Salad Dressing", "Lettuce",
    "Milk", "Eggo Frozen Waffles",
]
```

let's do this:

```
    // create a label to use for sizing
    let sizingLabel = UILabel()
    var sz: CGSize = .zero
    
    // max label width is one-half of main stack width
    //  minus column spacing (the center "gap")
    let maxW: CGFloat = floor((mainStack.bounds.width - columnSpacing) * 0.5)
    
    var curFontSize: CGFloat = maxFontSize
    var curFont: UIFont = .init(descriptor: defaultFont.fontDescriptor, size: curFontSize)
    
    // loop through all item labels...
    //  if the label is too wide, reduce the font size
    //  until the label fits, or we reach minimum font size
    sizingLabel.font = curFont
    for i in 0..<items.count {
        sizingLabel.text = items[i]
        sz = sizingLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        while ceil(sz.width) > maxW && curFontSize > minFontSize {
            curFontSize -= 0.5
            curFont = .init(descriptor: defaultFont.fontDescriptor, size: curFontSize)
            sizingLabel.font = curFont
            sz = sizingLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        }
    }

    // loop through the labels, setting font for all labels to the same calculated font size
    // eachLabel.font = curFont
```

So, one approach to get the layout you want is to use a vertical-axis stack view, with each "label pair" - or "row" - being a horizontal-axis stack view.

We can get this:

[image]

Like this - labels are yellow, vertical stack view background is cyan, custom view background is very light gray:

[image]

If we use a **max** font size of `16` and a **min** font size of `9`, all of these labels fit at `16`

[image]

if we add a *slightly-too-long* label, we can find the largest font size - that is less-than 16 - and set all labels to that font size:

[image]

adding a couple more "short" items, and we still use the font size that fits "Eggs Frozen Waffles":

[image]

Now we add "Birthday Cake for Tommy" and we get a little smaller:

[image]

When we add "Vanilla Birthday Cake for Tommy" we hit the **min** font size of `9`:

[image]

and so on:

[image]

[image]

I ***strongly recommend*** that you give it a try, using the code snippets above, so that you really understand what you need to do.

Here is some complete sample code you can play with...

---

**Custom `UIView` subclass:**

```
class MyListView: UIView {
    
    public var defaultFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var maxFontSize: CGFloat = 16.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var minFontSize: CGFloat = 9.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var rowSpacing: CGFloat = 4.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    // space between "columns" of item labels
    public var columnSpacing: CGFloat = 20.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    // "padding" around main stack view
    public var insets: UIEdgeInsets = .init(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0) {
        didSet { updateMainStack() }
    }
    
    // during development, toggle background colors so we can see the framing
    public var devColors: Bool = false { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var items: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            let numRows: Int = Int(ceil(Double(items.count) / 2.0))
            // remove any extra rows
            while mainStack.arrangedSubviews.count > numRows {
                mainStack.arrangedSubviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            // add any new rows
            while mainStack.arrangedSubviews.count < numRows {
                let rowStack = UIStackView()
                rowStack.axis = .horizontal
                rowStack.alignment = .top
                rowStack.spacing = columnSpacing
                rowStack.distribution = .fillEqually
                for _ in 0..<2 {
                    let label = UILabel()
                    rowStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
                }
                mainStack.addArrangedSubview(rowStack)
            }
            // clear current label refs
            labelRefs = []
            // get refs to the labels for convenience
            mainStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
                // we know what we're doing, but we want to safely unwrap anyway
                if let sv = v as? UIStackView, sv.arrangedSubviews.count == 2 {
                    if let vl = sv.arrangedSubviews[0] as? UILabel {
                        labelRefs.append(vl)
                    }
                    if let vl = sv.arrangedSubviews[1] as? UILabel {
                        labelRefs.append(vl)
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i, label) in labelRefs.enumerated() {
                // if we have an odd number of items, the
                //  last item-label will use " "
                label.text = i < items.count ? items[i] : " "
            }
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    // for convenience, so we can easily loop through all the item labels
    private var labelRefs: [UILabel] = []
    
    private let mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        updateMainStack()
    }
    
    // if the insets are changed, we need to "reset" the constraints
    private func updateMainStack() {
        mainStack.removeFromSuperview()
        addSubview(mainStack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: insets.top),
            mainStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: insets.left),
            mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -insets.right),
            mainStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -insets.bottom),
        ])
        mainStack.spacing = rowSpacing
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // column spacing may have changed
        mainStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            if let sv = v as? UIStackView {
                sv.spacing = columnSpacing
            }
        }
        
        // create a label to use for sizing
        let sizingLabel = UILabel()
        var sz: CGSize = .zero
        
        // max label width is one-half of main stack width
        //  minus column spacing (the center "gap")
        let maxW: CGFloat = floor((mainStack.bounds.width - columnSpacing) * 0.5)
        
        var curFontSize: CGFloat = maxFontSize
        var curFont: UIFont = .init(descriptor: defaultFont.fontDescriptor, size: curFontSize)
        
        // loop through all item labels...
        //  if the label is too wide, reduce the font size
        //  until the label fits, or we reach minimum font size
        sizingLabel.font = curFont
        for i in 0..<items.count {
            sizingLabel.text = items[i]
            sz = sizingLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
            while ceil(sz.width) > maxW && curFontSize > minFontSize {
                curFontSize -= 0.5
                curFont = .init(descriptor: defaultFont.fontDescriptor, size: curFontSize)
                sizingLabel.font = curFont
                sz = sizingLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
            }
        }
        
        labelRefs.forEach { v in
            // set font for all labels to the same calculated font size
            v.font = curFont

            // during development
            v.backgroundColor = devColors ? .yellow : .clear
        }

        // during development
        mainStack.backgroundColor = devColors ? .cyan : .clear

        // we probably want to adjust "row spacing" based on resulting font size
        mainStack.spacing = rowSpacing * (curFontSize / maxFontSize)
    }
    
}
```

---

**View Controller using that view:**

```
class FontMatchVC: UIViewController {
    
    let samples: [String] = [
        "Carrots", "Tomatos",
        "Bananas", "Cola",
        "Salad Dressing", "Lettuce",
        "Milk", "Eggo Frozen Waffles",
        "Soup", "Chicken",
        "Birthday Cake for Tommy", "Life Cereal",
        "Eggs", "Vanilla Birthday Cake for Tommy",
        "Chocalate Birthday Cake for Tommy", "Oatmeal",
        "Hot Dogs", "Hamburgers",
        "Ketchup",
    ]

    var itemCount: Int = 0
    
    let myListView = MyListView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // controls to add items and toggle dev-mode colors
        let controlsStack = UIStackView()
        controlsStack.axis = .vertical
        controlsStack.spacing = 8.0
        
        let tmpLabel = UILabel()
        tmpLabel.text = "Show Dev Mode Colors"
        let tmpSwitch = UISwitch()
        tmpSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleColors(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        let tmpStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [tmpLabel, tmpSwitch])
        controlsStack.addArrangedSubview(tmpStack)
        
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        btn.setTitle("Add Item", for: [])
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addItem(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        controlsStack.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.75, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0).isActive = true
        controlsStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.text = "Grocery List"
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        titleLabel.textColor = .white
        
        controlsStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(controlsStack)
        
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        myListView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myListView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            controlsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            controlsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            controlsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controlsStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            myListView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            myListView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            myListView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
        ])
        
        addItem(nil)
    }
    
    @objc func addItem(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        let n: Int = itemCount % samples.count
        myListView.items = Array(samples[0...n])
        itemCount += 1
    }

    @objc func toggleColors(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        myListView.backgroundColor = sender.isOn ? UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0) : .clear
        myListView.devColors = sender.isOn
    }
    
}
```

---

Looks like this when running:

[image]

"Add Item" button to change the items in the list, and a Switch to toggle the "Dev Mode" colors so we can easily see the framing.